# How to check all values passed by dictionary list in json?

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

My json is

```json
[{"Date":"2022-10-27","Delta":60,"Comment":null},{"Date":"2022-10-26","Delta":60,"Comment":null},{"Date":"2022-10-25","Delta":60,"Comment":null}]
```

I need to check that **all** Date values are greater than the current time. If so, return true, otherwise false.

I tried to do something like this:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM XXX WHERE Dates < GETDATE())
THEN CAST(0 AS BIT)
ELSE CAST(1 AS BIT) END
```

But I need a table XXX with all the `Dates` from my json. How do I get them?

And am I even thinking the right way to do this, or is there a better option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'[
  {"Date":"2022-10-27","Delta":60,"Comment":null},
  {"Date":"2022-10-26","Delta":60,"Comment":null},
  {"Date":"2022-10-25","Delta":60,"Comment":null}
]';

SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM OPENJSON(@json) AS x
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(value) AS y
  WHERE y.[key] = 'Date' 
  AND TRY_CONVERT(date, y.value, 120) < GETDATE()
) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;
```

You can put this in a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SniffOutBadDates
(
  @json nvarchar(max),
  @key  nvarchar(128),
  @when datetime
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN
  (
    SELECT AllDatesAreGood = CASE WHEN EXISTS
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM OPENJSON(@json) AS x
      CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(value) AS y
      WHERE y.[key] = @key 
        AND TRY_CONVERT(date, y.value, 120) < @when
    ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  );
```

Then call it against a table, like this:

```
SELECT t.id, f.AllDatesAreGood
  FROM dbo.YourTableName AS t
  CROSS APPLY dbo.SniffOutBadDates
              (t.jsonColumn, 'Date', GETDATE()) AS f;
```

Working example [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rNeeFQla).

Answer (score 0):

If you parse the input JSON using `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema (the `WITH` clause), you need a single statement:

```
SELECT IIF(
   COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(date, [Date], 23) > GETDATE() THEN 1 END), 
   1, 
   0
) AS [Result]
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH ([Date] varchar(10))
```

And if you want to use your current statement:

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
      WHEN EXISTS (
              SELECT 1 
              FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH ([Date] varchar(10)) 
              WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date, [Date], 23) < GETDATE()
         ) THEN CAST(0 AS BIT)
      ELSE 
         CAST(1 AS BIT) 
   END AS Result
```